# Detecting composite child items deleted

Tags: ria

Given a parent that contains child collection, attributed with:

```
[Include, Composition]
public virtual ICollection<FieldValue> FieldValues {get;set;}
```

and doing a load:

```
Context.Load(Context.GetQuery(),LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent,true);
```

I see that FieldValues deleted by another user or a background process don't get removed from the client context. I can see how this could be by design, but how do I work around this? Is there a way to plug into load process to handle the deleted items?

Load callback happens too late, by the looks of it - everything has been merged already, there's nothing to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Given a parent class Root, this is the way to run the load:

```
var originalValues = Context.EntityContainer
    .GetEntitySet<FieldValue>()
    .ToList(); // <-- make the pre-load copy of the child entities

Context.Load(Context.GetQuery(),
    LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent,
    (LoadOperation<Root> o) =>
    {
        (from v in originalValues
        join nv in o.AllEntities.OfType<FieldValue>() on v equals nv into g
        from existing in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where existing == null
        select v)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(Context.EntityContainer.GetEntitySet<FieldValue>().Detach);
    },
    null);
```

Note: FieldValue implements IEquatable<>, use PK if your child doesn't